# node.js to read usb port signals

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I have installed **serialport** module for node.js using npm.(`npm install serialport`).
Now I would like to send some messages from my android phone to node application via usb port of my computer(assuming node can read serial port signals).
Has anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Why, yes, it's certainly doable. There's a plenty of examples listed at the [serialport package homepage](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) itself.

Your node.js application will start with...

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/tty-usbserial1");

serialPort.on('data', function(data) { /* processing data */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But "/dev/tty-usbserial1" seems to be the path of the port in arduino? how can i specify the correct usb port address here(in windows)?

Comment: @Vivek What OS are you using?

Comment: "events.js:2076: Uncaught Error: Opening \\.\/dev/tty-usbserial1: Unknown error code 3" this is the error coming while using "/dev/tty-usbserial1"

Comment: TypeError: SerialPort is not a constructor

Answer (score 9):

For testing your ports on Windows (*you may have to install sf "**npm install sf**"*):

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var sf = require('sf');

serialport.list(function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var item = results[i];
    console.log(sf('{comName,-15} {pnpId,-20} {manufacturer}', item));
  }
});
```

Output should be something like:

COM8 FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+A100DKP7A\0000 FTDI 
COM1 ACPI\PNP0501\4&2E24A907&0 (Standardanschlusstypen)

Now use the port your device is connected to, in my case COM8:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM8");
```

regards