# How to identify USB port path/address in windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-7, usb

This question relates to [node.js to read usb port signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077223/node-js-to-read-usb-port-signals/12077561#comment16135151_12077561)

What is the possible way to get usb port address from windows7 32bit? For eg: If my phone is connected to one of the usb port how can i get the path/address of that USB port?

Comment: The way Windows handles USB is different than on linux/unix based systems.  Are you looking for a node.js solution or a native Win32 solution?

Comment: when Iam using "COM1" as the path, no exceptions will occur. otherwise it responds "file not found".(sorry if this comment has nothing to do with this question)

Comment: Check if https://github.com/tessel/node-usb helps you