# windows usb port 'address'

Tags: windows, node.js, serial-port, usb

I´m using node to make a litle project, and I´m trying to use the usb ports with SerialPort module (npm install serialport)... 
I make this:

```
var dev = 'the port of the device';
var sp = new com.SerialPort(dev,{baudrate:9600,parser:com.parsers.readline('\r\n')});
```

I am using Windows and I don´t know which is the path for port that must to use the usb. For example, with linux I know that something like this: "/dev/cu.usbmodemfd121" could works... but not with Windows.

I am trying to connect the pc with an arduino using node. I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077223/node-js-to-read-usb-port-signals/12077561#comment16135151_12077561) but nothing works.
I try this:

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var sf = require('sf');

serialport.list(function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var item = results[i];
    console.log(sf('{comName,-15} {pnpId,-20} {manufacturer}', item));
  }
});
```

I connect my mobile at usb, run the program and I can see nothing on the console....

Any suggestion?? any help, please??

PP: Excuse for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!! I was a little wrong, the code to know what devices are connected to your serial ports works fine.... but I don´t know why, not with my mobile (maybe it doen´t work good with all mobiles, or maybe only mine).
I talk about this code:

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var sf = require('sf');

serialport.list(function (err, results) 
{
    if (err) 
    {
       throw err;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
    {
       var item = results[i];
       console.log(sf('{comName,-15} {pnpId,-20} {manufacturer}', item));
    }
});
```

Thank you.